# How to calculate F-score using libsvm for java

Tags: java, machine-learning, libsvm, precision-recall

I have a training and test data set and they work perfectly with the default SVM code using LibSVM using Java. Can you please tell me how to get the confusion matrix and other values like Precision, Recall or atleast true positive rate(TPR), true negative rate(TNR), false positive rate(FPR) and false negative rate(FNR).

I am using command line so for file1.txt as training and tfile1.txt as test file. I am using the command line syntax which gives me the Accuracy %. The command is:-
Input: C:....\bin> java svm_predict file1.txt.model file1.out
Output: 70.135% Accuracy (157/224)

Is there a command line syntax for the program to display values like Precision, Recall, Fscore, TPR, TNR, FPR, FNR as well? What should I do? Please help!

Comment: I think you can search yourself for all these values. I don't know any implementation but on the other hand it's not so difficult to create them.

Comment: Thanks Eypros! I found a easier solution though. Use weka for additional details like Precision, Recall and F-Score. Just change your extension of libsvm files (example: from a.txt to a.libsvm), add libsvm.jar to classpath and convert all class values from numeric to nominal using weka filters as it does not support numeric labels for classes. Run it :)